# R Shiny dynamic tab number and input generation

Tags: r, loops, shiny

I've got an issue with my current shiny code.
I have to generate a dynamic number of tabs depending on the results of a given function (that part works fine). Then, I want to generate the input of these tabs in other loops of for example renderText. However, the final output of the textOutput for my generated renderText is always the one of the last renderText of the loops.

Here is a small example of the idea:

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)


 ui <- pageWithSidebar(
         headerPanel("xxx"),
         sidebarPanel(),
         mainPanel(
           uiOutput("multipleUI")
         )
      )


server <- function(input, output) {
      output$multipleUI <- renderUI({
      tabs <- list(NULL)
      for(i in 1:5){
          tabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(title = paste0("tab ",i),
                      textOutput(paste0("out",i)), # prints j as 5 in all tabs
                      paste0("local out ",i)) # prints i as current loop value for each tab)
     }
     do.call(tabBox,tabs)
  })
  observe({ 
    for(j in 1:5){ 
      txt = paste0("generated out ", j)
      print(txt) # print with current j
      output[[paste0("out",j)]] <- renderText({txt})
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While it might not be that important for renderText where I can just work around the issue, I intend to render a lot of plots and tables and couldn't think of a workaround there.

I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT: I've updated the code to show a small working example

Comment: Can you possibly post your whole `ui.R` and `server.R`, or `app.R` code so I can better visualize the problem?

Comment: yes, at least `tabBox` should be known.

Comment: @GauravBansal I've updated the code to show a small working example :)

Comment: To understand the problem, you want the line `textOutput(paste0("out",i))` to print out the tab number, instead of 5 each time, right?

Comment: @GauravBansal Yes in this example I'd like the textoutput to print the tab number (number which should have been setted in j).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that seems to work. I'm using `lapply` to create the tabs. Let me know if it works for what you need.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("xxx"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='tab',lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        title=paste0('tab ', i), 
        textOutput(paste0('out',i))
      )
    })))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {     
  lapply(1:5, function(j) {
    output[[paste0('out',j)]] <- renderPrint({
      paste0('generated out ', j)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help! By any chance, do you know why these work differently? I understand that in my example the problem has something to do with the fact that R is lazy and only sets the value of j upon calling it and that at this point it has the value 5. But I don't understand how lapply works differently.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out why your code didn't work.I used this site as a template for doing it with `lapply`: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html

Comment: Also, would you mind officially accepting my answer if you're fine with it so we can close out this question? Thanks.

Comment: Done :) sorry for the delay and thanks a lot for your help